# Can I test InAppPurchase in a real(using real cache) itunes environment? (not sandbox)

Tags: ios, swift, sandbox, tap

Can apps connect the real AppStore IAP environment? (not sandbox!)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as well, but I never found out how to do it. The sandbox pretty much works the same though, so you shouldn't have to use the production server. It has the same work-flow. It only looks different on production.

Ofcourse, you probably know, but don't forget to use the different verification url when uploading it to the App Store:

```
var restEndpoint: String = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        #if DEBUG
        do {
            restEndpoint = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        }
        #endif
```